# SP 2013 Foundation search in IE

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, search

Search works great with Firefox and Chrome but not with IE.
Search gives error:

> Unable to get property 'value' of undefined or null reference (CoreRender: `~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/Display Templates/Search/Control_SearchResults.js`)

Note! Site languge is Estonian. In Chrome/FF the language shows English.

Comment: What is the version of IE?

Comment: The version is 11.

Comment: Add your SharePoint Site URL in Compatibility View settings in IE 11 and then check if issue exist. If it is an intranet portal then tick the checkbox - Display intranet sites in CV. If it is an Internet website then tick the other checkbox - Display all pages in CV.

Comment: It is a intranet site. Added to CV and the problem remains.

Comment: Tick the checkbox - "Display all pages in CV" and check

Comment: There is no "Display all pages in CV" in IE11 anymore as I understand?

Answer (score 0):

> Microsoft failed to include IE11 browser support even after SharePoint 2013 SP1

The fix is to run the site in compatibility mode until SharePoint officially supports Internet Explorer 11. Or install IE 10.

or try [this workaround](http://sinclairinat0r.com/2014/03/06/internet-explorer-11-compatibility-fixes-for-sharepoint-2013/)

Comment: I tested my site with IE10 on Windows 7 machine and I get the same error. Can there be any other cause?

Comment: Please try this solution http://www.eliostruyf.com/ultimate-diagnostic-display-template/ .According to comments below ir should help you.